# How do I set Ionic header title left and center for few particular templates

Tags: ionic-framework, header

I'm working on Ionic project where in i should set header title to left for few templates and let it remain center for few templates is it possible? If so pls let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! You are supposed to show your attempt at solving the problem, and explain precisely why it doesn't work or doesn't fit to your expectations; or least what you have found in your research and why these solutions don't fit your case. Without a minimal and verifiable example of your code, we cannot help. [See how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I had tried using `align-title="center"` for templates which i need center as title and `align-title="left"` for rest but it dont work and remains center in all templates.

Comment: Ok, by the way it is better if you edit the question when you add information, lots of people won't even look at the comments. Still a bit vague, would be better to see the relevant bit of the code, like how the templates are loaded (there are different ways). The ionic version you are using too, because things changed a lot between some of them.